# Strange user account created

Tags: magento2

Hi I'm using magento 2 and recently I notice there are strange account accounts created.  We have in place an approval system that when a customer signs up we need to approve their account.  However, I'm not sure how its being done but there has been a few accounts that were created.  Does anyone know how this is done and how I can prevent this from happening?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install this extension.

https://github.com/enrico69/magento2-customer-activation

It will help you.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh answer edited.